# Xcode 8 MainStoryboard showing blue rectangles instead of objects

Tags: ios, xcode

I have latest version of Xcode 8 official release, and Im seeing blue rectangles borders filled white, instead of normal objects(Labels, Images, etc) on the main storyboard, I Drag an Image, button or anything and it just shows a blue rectangle (I don't see the object inside the rectangle, just an empty blue bordered rectangle), I attach an image for you guys to see, Any clue on how to solve it? Someone else with the same issue? This is happening an all My projects, and just start happening suddenly.. since the first day I was having no issue with this Xcode version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have accidentally switched on Layout Rectangles within Editor -> Canvas in Xcode menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, But It was not selected, I Actually see Just the Rectangles, but not the inside object!

Comment: So a combination of different items selected in that menu did not help?

Comment: I have tried different combinations and it is not showing the content inside rectangles yet :(

Comment: Try to switch Layout rects off, restart mac. This should help.

Comment: Restarting mac actually worked.. Can`t believe was that simple, Thanks for help!

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios so did my answer help you? :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution: Try these three steps.

1. Editor -> Canvas -> Turn OFF bounds rectangle.
2. Editor -> Canvas -> Turn ON bounds rectangle.
3. Editor -> Canvas -> Turn OFF bounds rectangle.

Comment: It's working, and I've also added a custom sort-cut so it makes the work faster 
Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings ( find bound rectangle add you key as per your choose )

Answer (score 2):

The contents of my storyboard views were actually not showing AND had blue rectangles, while 'Show Layout Rectangles' was NOT on. I was also surprised to see 'Show Bounds Rectangles' since I never turned them on (awesome Xcode ghost move here)

[image: Not seeing view content AND blue rectangles]

Note: Even though I did try turning 'Show Bounds Rectangles' off, the blue rectangles remained.

**Solution:** Restarting the computer. Opened to my storyboard and at least for me, I had to turn off 'Show Bounds Rectangles' because it still remained. I can see my content again, yay!

(seeing on Xcode 8.0)

Answer (score 2):

I tried lots of solution. But there is no permanent fix for this.

Try below line

> Editor->Canvas->Bounds Rectangles. (Do this three times.)

Doing this every time is quite annoying. So a solution is u can set some shortcut key (Keybinding).

Go in Xcode-> Settings/Preferences -> Keybinding -> search Bounds Rectangles and set shortcut for that

[image: This ss editor menu]
[image: Shortcut key i have used]

It will be easy if we use shortcut and save some time.