# Getting Blue lines in Storyboard ViewController Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode

Image showing blue lines. After XCode 14 update in a day i encounter this almost 10 times. Only solution is every-time i restart xcode. Does anyone has some other solution?

[image: Attached Image]

Comment: I found a quick fix. You can can go through this link , m sure its gonna share your time.https://stackoverflow.com/a/74487772/11872367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sre the features simply change it go in the editor and do the following

Storyboard> Editor> Canvas> Show Bounds Rectangles

Answer (score 8):

Repeat this step 3 times:

1. **Editor -> Canvas -> Bound Rectangles**

Comment: This one worked bro. Thanks a lot. :) . Don't Know why people are giving negative marks to the questions.

Comment: @BilalKhan this is a duplicate question, that's why.

Comment: Ok bro.But i asked coz it dint get solved. Nvm thnx for ur help. Saved a loads of time.

Comment: it worked only at 3rd time

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not issue or bug. It is one features provided by Apple Inc. in new Xcode version by default. It shows that how actually controls shows on your screen, so it try to show us grid with blue lines when we put any control on storyboard.

Also you can hide those blue lines by

Open app in Xcode --> Select Storyboard --> Editor --> Canvas --> Show Bounds Rectangles

Comment: Tried this bro. But i got the issue solved by @Taimoor Arif Answer. Still thanks to you for your time. :)